# Why I can't add TemplateField to div html element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use asp.net 4.5 in my project.
I try to add control in code behind bu I get error.

Here is my HTML code from view:

```
<div class="row" id="_FooterPanel"  runat="server"></div>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public void FooterPanelInit()
{
    var myFooterTemplate = new TemplateField();
    var viewFooter = new ViewFooterTemplate();
    var editFooter = new EditFooterTemplate();

    myFooterTemplate.ItemTemplate = viewFooter;
    myFooterTemplate.EditItemTemplate = editFooter;
    _FooterPanel.Controls.Add(myFooterTemplate);
}
```

In code above I try to add to div with `id="_FooterPanel"` the `TemplateField`.

But in this row:

```
_FooterPanel.Controls.Add(myFooterTemplate);
```

I get this error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'

My question is how can I add `TemplateField` to div with `id="_FooterPanel"`?

Comment: Seems like `<div>`only accepts `Control` child elements. You will need to use a templated control instead.

Comment: Could you provide a little context to your problem? If you need to make the content of your `<div>` editable, you could use `<asp:PlaceHolder>`. Maybe check [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

Comment: A `TemplateField` is only used inside a GridView. It is not a standalone Control.

Answer (score 1):

TemplateField is databound control of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField' but div control can have collection of controls of type System.Web.UI.Control
so you may use repeater control instead of div with runat='server'
or use your custom user control

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to do?